# Excel: Using IF function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to get a solution where if, Column C1*D1*E1 >= 118 the answer Column returns `NA`, but if less than 118, I want it to return the multiplied value of (`C1*D1*E1`).

Below is an Example:

```
      C1             D1               E1            F1 (Result)
Length(Inches)   Width (Inches) Height (Inches)
      48              45             38             NA (as C1*D1*E1 was more than 118 it returned NA)
      3                2              3             **NEED HELP HERE**
```

I want a formula which can return `NA` if value is more than 118, but if less than 118, I want it to give me the multiplied value of `C1*D1*E1` in `F1`.

Answer (score 4):

```
=IF(C1*D1*E1>=118,"NA",C1*D1*E1)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. It worked.

Comment: @Ricky - if the answer helped to solve the issue, it would be helpful if you marked it as the correct answer by checking the ✓ symbol.